# Reading in a GeoJSON page with AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, gis, geojson

I spent hours trying to figure out how to read in a URL page with GeoJSON with AngularJS and $http.get.   I started out with the example from:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

but it doesn't seem to work with GeoJSON webpage.  I tried using Leaflet but I couldn't get it to work either.   The GeoJSON page I'm try to read in with AngularJS with $http.get is:

http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json

Is it not possible to use AngularJS and $http.get with GeoJSON pages?   If anyone could provide any advice I would be very grateful.   Thank you.

Dave

Comment: What do you mean it's not working ? You have some content back but it's not recognized as GeoJSON ? Maybe use JSON.parse on the data ?

Comment: Regarding the above *duplicate*, the problem is no CORS headers. Also, ~22MB is kinda big to be loading into an Angular app

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't allow cross-origin requests when I tested: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_050_00_500k.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Try targeting a different API that allows CORS.